# Decomposition of variation into cross-sectional and time series variation

Tags: variance, panel-data, variance-decomposition

I have a panel dataset covering 20 counties and I have 150 monthly datapoints for each country. Specifically, my data consists of stock returns from each individual country. I want to dig deeper into how the returns vary across countries and across time. From a referee I got the comment that I should decompose the variation of the return data into cross-sectional and time series variation. How could I do this decomposition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does nobody has an idea?

Comment: If you are using a statistical package such as Stata this is actually quite straightforward to do. What you are looking is akin to within/between groups variance decomposition. For example, you can do it using the `xtsum` command in stata. See more information [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtsum.pdf).

Comment: This paper discusses the problem:  https://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2014/201462/201462pap.pdf